# Not able to add keyboard shorcut that starts with the `Super` key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just reinstalled my workstation to 20.04.3. In the past, I custom configured a couple of keyboard shortcuts that start with the Super key. I can add other keyboard shortcuts that include Super also but not any that start with Super. The one I'm missing the most is `Super + n` to start Nautilus. Now I can not add this anymore.

How I try to add the shortcut:

- `Settings`
- `Keyboard Shorcuts`
- Scroll down to the button of the page
- Hit `+` button
- Select `Set Shortcut` (from the small opened window)
- Enter a new shortcut using the keyboard: `Super + n`

  - at this point, nothing happens.
  - But if I start with other keys as the first key even if the Super key is part of the shortcut the new shortcut will be recorded. For example this works `Alt + Super + N` and then I'm back to the new small window and the shortcut was recorded and displayed. Now all is left is to type in the command and set a name for this shortcut.

I'm using a fresh Gnome Ubuntu instalation

```
bogdan@bogdan-pc ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Supper on its own works. It correctly displays the overview.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Please edit your question and include some more specific details: where and how are you trying to set shortcut definitions, what happens and what you expect to happen. What do you mean by "other shortcuts that include Super"? Are you using the standard Ubuntu desktop? Does Super on its own work to display the overview?

Comment: I edited my question as requested.

Comment: Very clear now! Is this a fresh install or an upgrade? Can't you set other Super+<letter> keys? By default, Super+n is used by the system, but normally you should receive a warning. Are you working on Xorg or on Wayland (you can tell from the command `printenv XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: @vanadium This is a fresh install from 03 December 2021. `printenv XDG_SESSION_TYPE` -> `x11`. In case Super+n is used by the system I would definitely like to change it.